# Application.LoadScene (now SceneManager.LoadScene) is not working and Unity 5.3.1p3 crashes

Tags: crash, scene, unity-game-engine

I'm using OS X El Capitan and Unity 5.3.1p3. My project was working, but after this last update, the project crashed. Trying to load the next scene using `SceneManager.LoadScene("BeforeScene")` from the first scene is problem.

When this code runs, Unity crashes and it closes. What can I do for this problem?

Comment: Have you made sure that your scenes are added to the scene hierarchy? They may have removed themselves during the crash for some strange reason.

Comment: You're sure you have a scene called "BeforeScene"?